# Interface inheritance without return type covariance

Tags: c#, interface, covariance, return-type

Let's say I have a simple C# interface of the following type

```
public interface ITimeSeriesData

ITimeSeriesData Add(ITimeSeries timeSeries)
```

This interface represents the contract for a set of time series data. For simplicity, I only included a single method, namely that for adding a time series and obtaining a new set of data corresponding to this addition (think of the data as immutable, so when a new time series is added, the original instance is unchanged, and a new set of time series data is returned). I also have another interface, which represents the contract for classes also containing time series data, but where it is enforced that all the time series contain the same number of elements.

```
public interface ISquareTimeSeriesData

ISquareTimeSeriesData Add(ITimeSeries timeSeries)
```

Now, ideally, I'd like any ISquareTimeSeriesData to be an ITimeSeriesData. And with return type covariance, I could simply write

```
public interface ISquareTimeSeriesData : ITimeSeriesData

ISquareTimeSeriesData Add(ITimeSeries timeSeries)
```

and since any ISquareTimeSeriesData then would be an ITimeSeriesData, I'd have that any class implementing the "ISquareTimeSeriesData Add(ITimeSeries timeSeries)" method also would count as implementing "ITimeSeriesData Add(ITimeSeries timeSeries)". However, C# does not have return type covariance, so the above solution does not work.

Is there an elegant way out of this? Currently, I simply have a method .AsTimeSeriesData() in the ISquareTimeSeriesData interface which returns any ISquareTimeSeriesData as a ITimeSeriesData. This is not particularly elegant, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by hiding the original interface `Add` method, although this is far from ideal. It is possible though to make a working solution out of it though.

```
public interface ITimeSeriesData
{
    ITimeSeriesData Add(ITimeSeries timeSeries);
}

public interface ISquareTimeSeriesData : ITimeSeriesData
{
    new ISquareTimeSeriesData Add(ITimeSeries timeSeries); // hide original
}

public class STSD : ISquareTimeSeriesData
{
    public ISquareTimeSeriesData Add(ITimeSeries timeSeries)
    {
        // implement here
    }

    ITimeSeriesData ITimeSeriesData.Add(ITimeSeries timeSeries)
    {
        return this.Add(timeSeries); // call the overridden Add method
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the solution makes sense. However, as far as I can understand, it requires classes implementing ISquareTimeSeriesData to implement both Add methods (both the one for ITimeSeriesData and the one for ISquareTimeSeriesData). Thus, if I iterate this solution (e.g. having a IDoubleSquareTimeSeriesData implementing ISquareTimeSeriesData), I'd end up having to implement three Add methods and so forth. But I guess there's not much to do about that.